# Помогите с Python3, def и input: как сделать ввод, чтобы если введя в него Bot_Advice() началась функция Bot_Advice()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотел сделать небольшого консольного бота.

```
import re

print('This is bot beta-version')
username = input('Your username > ')

def Bot_Advice():
    a = input("> ")
    ans = re.findall(r'advice film|advice music', a)
    if ans == ['advice film']:
        print('bla-bla-bla')
    elif ans == ['advice music']:
        print('bla-bla-bla')
```

Но, как ни странно, консоль прекращает проект, потому что больше нигде ввода нет. Как сделать ввод, чтобы если введя в него `Bot_Adice()` началась функция `Bot_Advice()`?

Comment: Если что отступы есть

Comment: Так расставьте их, иначе как понять, что не в них проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял вам нужна примерна вот такая конструкция?

```
import re

def Bot_Advice():
    a = input("> ")
    ans = re.findall(r'advice film|advice music', a)
    if ans == ['advice film']:
        print('bla-bla-bla')
    elif ans == ['advice music']:
        print('bla-bla-bla')


while True:
    print('This is bot beta-version')
    username = input('Your username > ')
    if username == 'Bot_Advice()':
        Bot_Advice()
    else:
        pass
```